# Replacing hyphens in words with the next letter capitalized

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a symbol like the following. Whenever the symbol contains the "-" hyphen mark, I want to remove it and upcase the subsequent letter. 
I am able to do it like so:

```
sym = :'new-york'
str = sym.to_s.capitalize
/-(.)/.match(str)     
str = str.gsub(/-(.)/,$1.capitalize)     
=> "NewYork"
```

This required four lines. Is there a more elegant way to create CamelCase (upper CamelCase e.g. NewYork, NewJersey, BucksCounty) from hyphened words in Ruby?

Comment: Your question suggests "newYork" is to be returned, but you show "NewYork".

Comment: @CarySwoveland I now mentioned camelcase words

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `str.gsub(/-(.)/,$1.capitalize)` won’t work as expected. Try it on `santiago-de-chile`. It works in your example only because there is the only hyphen.

Comment: to @CarySwoveland's point camel case means different things such as camelCase (called camel case or lower camel case) or CamelCase (also called camel case or Pascal Case or upper camel case). Your question requests the first and states the second is correct thus the confusion. Also the use of 4 lines is superfluous especially the third line which has no implication.

Comment: Further to the last two comments, I suggest you edit to state your question precisely. You need to clarify whether there is one hyphen or possibly two or more, and what you want done with the strings that would be obtained if you were to split the string on hyphens. I wouldn't change it now, but the fact you are starting with a symbol is distracting, as the first step in all answers is to convert it to a string. I think it would have been better to just present a string in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sym.to_s.gsub(/(-|\A)./) { $&[-1].upcase }
```

or

```
sym.to_s.gsub(/(-|\A)./) { |m| m[-1].upcase }
```

Comment: Is \A the same thing as [A-Z]?

Comment: Not at all. `\A` is a beginning-of-string matcher. I use it to avoid the necessity to explicitly capitalize the string to make the very first letter upcased.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:

```
sym.to_s.split('-').map(&:capitalize).join #=> "NewYork"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    ([[:alpha:]]+) # match 1 or more letters in capture group 1
    -              # match a hyphen
    ([[:alpha:]]+) # match 1 or more letters in capture group 2
    /x             # free-spacing regex definition mode

sym = :'new-york'
sym.to_s.sub(r) { $1.capitalize + $2.capitalize }
  #=> "NewYork"
```